# Dealing with unstructured data in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have unstructured data in a column in the format

```
[{
  "M": {
    "accountNumber": {
      "S": "1000022"
    },
    "orgUrns": {
      "L": [{
        "S": "cmp-pp-org-310"
      }, {
        "S": "cmp-pp-org-7096"
      }, {
        "S": "cmp-pp-org-7097"
      }]
    }
  }
}]
```

From this I want to separate `accountNumber` and `orgUurn` into separate column .

Tried many ways but not getting result. Can any one suggest solution?

Comment: Please update your question to show what you’ve tried. Also, what is the datatype of the column holding this semi-structured data?

Answer (score 0):

putting your data into a CTE:

```
WITH data(json) as (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) from values
        ('[{"M":{"accountNumber":{"S":"1000022"},"orgUrns":{"L":[{"S":"cmp-pp-org-310"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7096"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7097"}]}}}]')
)
```

this sql uses [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) twice to unroll the two arrays (the outer array, and the inner array of `L`

```
SELECT 
    f.value:M:accountNumber,
    o.value
FROM data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f,
    table(flatten(input=>f.value:M:orgUrns:L)) o
    ;
```

gives:

| F.VALUE:M:ACCOUNTNUMBER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| { "S": "1000022" } | { "S": "cmp-pp-org-310" } |
| { "S": "1000022" } | { "S": "cmp-pp-org-7096" } |
| { "S": "1000022" } | { "S": "cmp-pp-org-7097" } |

which could have those final value access cleaned up a little like:

```
SELECT 
    f.value:M:accountNumber:S::number as accountNumber ,
    o.value:S::text as orgUrn
FROM data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f,
    table(flatten(input=>f.value:M:orgUrns:L)) o
```

| ACCOUNTNUMBER | ORGURN |
| --- | --- |
| 1000022 | cmp-pp-org-310 |
| 1000022 | cmp-pp-org-7096 |
| 1000022 | cmp-pp-org-7097 |

### Re Comment:

So the code to use ether need to include the [CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html):

```
WITH data(json) as (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) from values
        ('[{"M":{"accountNumber":{"S":"1000022"},"orgUrns":{"L":[{"S":"cmp-pp-org-310"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7096"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7097"}]}}}]')
)
SELECT 
    f.value:M:accountNumber:S::number as accountNumber ,
    o.value:S::text as orgUrn
FROM data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f,
    table(flatten(input=>f.value:M:orgUrns:L)) o
    ;
```

Or you have to create a table, which takes time as I have to clean it up

```
CREATE TABLE data(json variant);

INSERT INTO data select parse_json('[{"M":{"accountNumber":{"S":"1000022"},"orgUrns":{"L":[{"S":"cmp-pp-org-310"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7096"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7097"}]}}}]');

SELECT 
    f.value:M:accountNumber:S::number as accountNumber ,
    o.value:S::text as orgUrn
FROM data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f,
    table(flatten(input=>f.value:M:orgUrns:L)) o
    ;
```

Or you put the JSON parsing into the middle of the SQL and that also can be confusing.

```
SELECT 
    f.value:M:accountNumber:S::number as accountNumber ,
    o.value:S::text as orgUrn
FROM table(flatten(input=>parse_json('[{"M":{"accountNumber":{"S":"1000022"},"orgUrns":{"L":[{"S":"cmp-pp-org-310"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7096"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7097"}]}}}]'))) f,
    table(flatten(input=>f.value:M:orgUrns:L)) o
    ;
```

Comment: Hi Simeon, Am working this in snowflake and the first code you have given is not working                      WITH data(json) as (
    SELECT parse_json(column1) from values
        ('[{"M":{"accountNumber":{"S":"1000022"},"orgUrns":{"L":[{"S":"cmp-pp-org-310"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7096"},{"S":"cmp-pp-org-7097"}]}}}]')
)

Comment: Yes, the  first block needs to be infront/before the other blocks. It is tempsry data, so i dont have to create table. I provide it so you can test the code and see it working. For context it called a CTE or common table expression.